# Create a proxy for a dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, proxy, dependency-properties

I am trying to create a simple dependency property proxy. I made a custom control, it's a file picker, which is made off a textbox (name: `"TextBox_FilePath"`) and a button showing the open file dialog.

As I am making a reusable control I'd like it to have a `"SelectedFilePath"` property. As the `Text` property seems to be perfect for my control to be the `"SelectedFilePath"` property, I'd just like to proxy these dependency property.

The first approach I made was:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilePathProperty = TextBox.TextProperty;

public string SelectedFilePath
{
    get { return (string) this.TextBox_FilePath.GetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty); }
    set { this.TextBox_FilePath.SetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty, value); }
}
```

which worked, but throwed an exception when trying to bind to that property. Then I came off with:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilePathProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFilePath", typeof (string), typeof (FilePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string SelectedFilePath
{
    get { return (string) this.TextBox_FilePath.GetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty); }
    set { this.TextBox_FilePath.SetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty, value); }
}
```

which does work, but I've got no idea why?! Where did I specify I wanted the `text` property of the textbox?

**What am I missing to simply proxy out that dependency property?**

**EDIT:**
The solution with `AddOwner` doesn't work too, it throws an Excetion saying "binding can only be applied on a dependency property". Code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilePathProperty =
    TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FilePicker));

public string SelectedFilePath
{
    get { return (string)this.TextBox_FilePath.GetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty); }
    set { this.TextBox_FilePath.SetValue(SelectedFilePathProperty, value); }
}
```

What don't I understand?

**EDIT2:**
For everybody else having issues understanding the answer, I've made [a little graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10997648/808723)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach does not work because the property is *registered* only for the `TextBox`, adding a reference in another class does nothing.

The second one just creates a whole new string property.

If you really want to reuse the `TextBox.TextProperty` call [`AddOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DependencyProperty.AddOwner.aspx) on it.

e.g.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilePathProperty =
    TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FilePicker));
```

(Note that this property is registered as `"Text"`, so you probably should just create a new property with the name you want as you did already. I would also recommend to [set metadata flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557295.aspx) to [bind two-way by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) if you want to have the same binding behaviour as `TextBox.Text`.)

Comment: *As i said*, it's registered with the name "Text", you can hence only bind to a property called `Text`, the `SelectedFilePath` property you created is just a wrapper for convenience in your imperative code, the bindings never use it. Register your own property if you want a different name.

Comment: May you be so kind and provide an example or give any reference on how to do that?

Comment: @GameScripting: You already did that in your second code block. There is no real need to reuse the `TextBox.Text`, it does nothing special, just go with your own property.

Comment: But where does `AddOwner` go then?

Comment: So to "proxy out" a property I simply declare my own and bind the control property (`TextBox.Text`) to my own property, so everything stays in sync?

Comment: @GameScripting: Nothing syncs magically. What exactly do you want to do? If you just want some text in your control you can create your own property and bind it to a `TextBox` in the `ControlTemplate` via a `TemplateBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a little tricky but works.

Given this user control:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <WpfApplication1:FilePicker SelectedFilePath ="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And its viewmodel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string e)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
    }

    #endregion

    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML for FilePicker control:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox_FilePath" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type WpfApplication1:FilePicker}}}" Text="{Binding SelectedFilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind for FilePicker control:

```
public partial class FilePicker : UserControl
{
    public FilePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /* private PROXY DP*/
    private static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(FilePicker));

    /* public DP that will fire getter/setter for private DP  */
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedFilePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedFilePath", typeof(string), typeof(FilePicker), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string SelectedFilePath
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you very much, without your example I wouldn't get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

As I had issues understanding [H.B.s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982729/808723) I made a little graphic which helped me to understand what's going on under the hood. Here it is;

[image]

Maybe it helps someone else :)

Comment: Now i get what it was that you did not get :P